# Error trying to build custom Ubuntu 18.04 iso using xorriso

Tags: bash, iso

```
#!/bin/bash

# The example names get mapped to their roles here
orig_iso="$HOME"/iso/foxclone.iso
new_iso="$HOME"/iso/foxclone025-02.iso
mbr_template="$HOME"/isohdpfx.bin
workdir="$HOME"/work
echo $HOME
echo $workdir is workdir
# Extract MBR template file to disk
dd if="$orig_iso" bs=1 count=432 of="$mbr_template"

# Create the new ISO image
xorriso -as mkisofs \
   -U  \
   -allow-lowercase  \
   -r -V 'foxclone025-02' \
   -o "$new_iso" \
   -J -J -joliet-long \
   -isohybrid-mbr "$mbr_template" \
   -b "$workdir"/isolinux/isolinux.bin \   <--------  fails here. The file does exist at that location.
   -c isolinux/boot.cat \
   -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -no-emul-boot \
   -eltorito-alt-boot \
   -e boot/grub/efi.img \
   -no-emul-boot -isohybrid-gpt-basdat -isohybrid-apm-hfsplus
```

[Error in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo2FP.png)
I've been trying to fix this for 2 days, doing a crazy amount of research. Does anybody see anything that my old eyes have missed?

EDIT: Got it fixed by changing the line:

```
 xorriso -as mkisofs \
```

to

```
 xorriso -as mkisofs "$workdir" \
```

and removing the reference to `$workdir` in the `-b` line

Answer (score 0):

the complaint of xorriso says that the -b file is not found in the ISO.
In the command i see two reasons for this:

1: You use the absolute disk path instead of the path in the ISO.

2: There is no xorriso argument to see by which the file would get into the
ISO. Actually no files at all seem to get mapped into the ISO.

Proposal:

If you want all files of "$workdir" in the ISO, add argument "$workdir".

If you expect isolinux.bin to show up in /isolinux/ of the ISO, remove
from the path of option -b the prefix "$workdir"/ so that the path complies
to the prescription of both, mkisofs and xorrisofs (*).

```
xorriso -as mkisofs ... -b isolinux/isolinux.bin ... "$workdir"
```

(*) mkisofs demands disk paths "relative to the source path", xorrisofs demands
paths in the emerging ISO. Default working directory in the ISO is /. So the
path "isolinux/isolinux.bin" is usable and advised for both.

See how Debian packs up its x86 bootable ISOs in principle:
  https://wiki.debian.org/RepackBootableISO#Remove_the_unneeded_Jigdo_production_options

(Support mailing list for xorriso is bug-xorriso@gnu.org.)

Have a nice day :)

Thomas

Comment: Thomas, I tried -b isolinux/isolinux.bin, it doesn't work without the path either. Is it looking at the original .iso or the extracted iso?

Comment: The extracted iso is located in $workdir and that is where I'm running the script from, not my $HOME.

Comment: This has been solved. Had a couple of files from wrong version of Ubuntu